# Python Split output column with fixed & dynamic length

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy

I want to split the data frame from a single column to three columns  [Sample input and output](https://pastebin.com/DYmn65V6) 
[(Col1=fix length), (Col2=*dynamic length*),( Col3= remaining part)]

```
import re
import pandas as pd
text='Raw Data'
out = re.findall(r"RIY-[A-Z]{6}-\d{6}\.\d{6,8}\.\d{5,7}", text) 
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = ["RIY"]) 

df["col1"] = df.RIY.str[0:15]
df["col2"] = df.RIY.str[15:24]# need to split based on criteria (find next '.' less 2 char
df["col3"] = df.RIY.str[24:] # remaining all text after splitting 2 column

#Output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lupcd.png
```

I tried to split with a fixed length (solution by Roy2012) which only works perfectly, For the first part, [0:15], length varies for the remaining two columns. I want to split by finding second dot('.') less (-2) (to avoid removing 46) I want to achieve by (find the second dot(.) -2 (to avoid removing 46) then split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this working for you?

```
df.RAW.str.extract(r"(.*)(\d\d\.\d+)(\d\d\.\d+)")
```

The output I get is:

```
                 0          1          2
0  RIY-OUHOMH-1002  24.534768  46.650127
1  RIY-OUHOHH-1017   24.51472  46.663988
2  RIY-OUHOMH-1004  24.532244  46.651758
3  RIY-OUHOHH-1007  24.529029  46.653571
4  RIY-OUHOHH-1006  24.530071  46.651934
5  RIY-OUHOHH-1005  24.531786   46.65279
6  RIY-OUHOMH-1001  24.535972  46.649456
7  RIY-DIRAHH-0151  24.495407  46.641877
8  RIY-DIRAHH-0152  24.494105  46.644253
```